# can we authenticate with response type as access token in MSAL JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-msal

In Our application uses AAD for authenticating the corporate users within our organization only.

Is that possible to set the response type as access token instead of default id_token ? Here is my config.

```
  // const msalConfig = {
  //   auth: {
  //     clientId: configuration.msal.clientId,
  //     tenantId:configuration.msal.tenantId,
  //     redirectUri: window.location.href
  //   },
  //   cache: {
  //     cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
  //     storeAuthStateInCookie: true
  //   }
  // };
```

I get the error as but if i enable id_token in authentication under Azure App registrations authentication it works again.. but is that possible to get the authentication done just with access token enabled.

```
 msal handleRedirectCallback ServerError: AADSTS700054: response_type 'id_token' is not enabled for 
 the application.
```

T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. MSAL.JS is used implement browser level flows like
   [implicit flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow).
2. Id token is required for implicit flow  to validate that a user is
   who they claim to be and get additional useful information about
   Then for security purpose.
3. In implicit flow we need to first authorize with id token and then only we can request for access token.
4. Implicit flow  is recommended only if the application has a single-page architecture (SPA), has no back-end components.

You are facing the error because implicit flow is not enabled.

To enable implicit flow please check Access tokens and ID tokens in your registered application as mentioned below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to use Authorization Code Flow ? If so, you have to use [MSAL v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser).

EDIT: sorry, I misread the question.

You cannot directly ask for an access token with MSAL, you have to login first (`id_token`) and then acquire a token (`access_token`).
This is all explained in [the docs](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-core#usage).